# what do hidden layers mean in a neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

in a standard neural network, I'm trying to understand, intuitively, what the values of a hidden layer mean in the model.

I understand the calculation steps, but I still dont know how to think about the hidden layers and how interpret the results (of the hidden layer)

So for example, given the standard MNIST datset that is used to train and predict handwritten digits between 0 to 9, a model would look like this:

1. An image of a handwritten digit will have 784 pixels.
2. Since there are 784 pixels,  there would be 784 input nodes and the value of each node is the pixel intensity(0-255)
3. each node branches out and these branches are the weights.
4. My next layer is my hidden layer, and the value of a given node in the hidden layer is the weighted sum of my input nodes (pixels*weights).
5. Whatever value I get, I squash it with a sigmoid function and I get a value between 0 and 1.

That number that I get from the sigmoid.  What does it represent exactly and why is it relevant?  My understanding is that if I want to build more hidden layers, I'll be using the values of my initial hidden layer, but at this point, i'm stuck as to what the values of the first hidden layer mean exactly.

Thank you!

Comment: As far as i know, there is no specific name for it if you use a simple neural network nodes. If you use a convolution neural network, those are called "activation maps". In simple laymen terms we can call it as features, because from 784, you might have reduced it to 500 nodes(hidden nodes) and extracted only that many features. Over the period of time of training, the nodes with specific features gets activated (higher value in sigmoid) and the other dont.

Comment: They're also are called hidden, because they're neither inputs nor outputs, just like input to function is known,  output is eventually too, technically everything inside it is a black box, as long as you don't read source of it, it is hidden. While in a NN this is not equivalent... Input nodes fire... And then it enters hidden layer, which cannot be influenced or accessed by input directly. It's wrapped in two, less restricted sides, and we aren't very creative when it comes to naming things, hence "hidden". There's no special meaning behind it. It's as special as a word "input" for in data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a very basic example of AND, OR, NOT and XOR functions.

You may already know that a single neuron is only suitable when the problem is linearly separable.

Here in this case, AND, OR and NOT functions are linearly separable and so they can be easy handled using a single neuron.

But consider the XOR function. It is not linearly separable. So a single neuron will not be able to predict the value of XOR function.
Now, XOR function is a combination of AND, OR and NOT. Below equation is the relation between them:

> a XOR b = (a AND (NOT b)) OR ((NOT a) AND b)

So, for XOR, we can use a network which contain three layers.
First layer will act as NOT function, second layer will act as AND of the output of first layer and finally the output layer will act as OR of the 2nd hidden layer.

Note: This is just a example to explain why it is needed, XOR can be implemented in various other combination of neurons.

Comment: This still does not exactly address the meaning of the values in a model's first hidden layer, post-activation, as the OP asks for.

Answer (score 0):

A hidden layer in a neural network may be understood as a layer that is neither an input nor an output, but instead is an intermediate step in the network's computation.

In your MNIST case, the network's state in the hidden layer is a processed version of the inputs, a reduction from full digits to abstract information *about* those digits.

This idea extends to all other hidden layer cases you'll encounter in machine learning -- a second hidden layer is an even more abstract version of the input data, a recurrent neural network's hidden layer is an interpretation of the inputs that happens to collect information over time, or the hidden state in a convolutional neural network is an interpreted version of the input with certain features isolated through the process of convolution.

To reiterate, a hidden layer is an intermediate step in your neural network's process.  The information in that layer is an abstraction of the input, and holds information required to solve the problem at the output.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, for this digit recognition case, one way to think about it is each level of the hidden layers represents the level of abstraction.

For now, imagine the neural network for digit recognition has only 3 layers which is 1 input layer, 1 hidden layer and 1 output layer.

Let's take a look at a number. To recognise that it is a number we can break the picture of the number to a few more abstract concepts such as lines, circles and arcs. If we want to recognise `6`, we can first recognise the more abstract concept that is exists in the picture. for `6` it would be an arc and a circle for this example. For `8` it would be 2 circles. For `1` it would be a line.

It is the same for a neural network. We can think of layer 1 for pixels, layer 2 for recognising the abstract concept we talked earlier such as lines, circles and arcs and finally in layer 3 we determine which number it is.

Here we can see that the input goes through a series of layers from the most abstract layer to the less abstract layer (pixels -> line, circle, arcs -> number). In this example we only have 1 hidden layer but in real implementation it would be better to have more hidden layer that 1 depending on your interpretation of the neural network. Sometime we don't even have to think about what each layer represents and let the training do it fo us. That is the purpose of the training anyway.